# Looking to modify the links on a page with greasemonkey/javascript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

With greasemonkey, I'd like to replace all the links on a page that end with `?####` - the #### being random characters) with the `?####` removed.

For example:

Replace the default url
`http//mysite.com/a/b-b1/product1/?####`
with
`http//mysite.com/a/b-b1/product1/`

this is what I've got:

```js
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  var n = anchors.indexOf('?');
  link = anchors.substring(0, n != - 1 ? n : anchors.length);
  anchors[i].href = link.href
}
```

I've tried this as well

```js
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('?'));
```

Neither one does anything. Do you see something wrong with this snippet? Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've simply forgotten to apply the index on the anchor collection.

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  anchors[i].href = anchors[i].href.split("?")[0];
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Simple. Works great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've not used indexes to retrieve the elements out of `NodeList`

However, you can do it with some old-school loops and if-conditions and with some help of regex.

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++)
    anchors[i].href = anchors[i].href.replace(/\?.*/, "");
```

I've used regex simply because, it removes the need to check for `?` and then using substring functions.. It's simple. It replaces anything after `?` inclusively, only if it's present. If it's not, no replace occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your alternate solution.

Comment: @KiloJKilo glad to have helped :)